# 10G NIC Dual port - Will I get ~10G throughput on both ports simultaneously

Tags: network

I have a dual port 10G NIC. I need to know if it is possible to get ~10G throughput in both the ports simultaneously?

If yes, how can I test it out?

If no, then will both port have ~5G thoughput each?

Comment: I think you are asking server or client level configuration, It is off topic here. However in windows server environment nic teaming load balance mode is answer for your question

Comment: Nope, I'm just asking about the NIC capabilities. No server or client level configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, a NIC, is in an end-device (host/server), and it is off-topic here. In any case, the question is too broad without the specific model, software, and configuration.

Comment: So, NIC is an e2e device and it does not come into Network engineering? Is that what you are saying? https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic My question is on the physical infrastructure section. I don't see a reason to put my question on hold if the network cable color code is acceptable. It is a generic question that comes when doing network infra planning. If you still feel that my question is off-topic - I can delete my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each port represents a (mostly) independent network interface.

You should be able to get maximum duplex throughput on both ports simultaneously (20 Gbit/s in + 20 Gbit/s out), provided the slot, the mainboard and the data source/sink are up to it.

20 Gbit/s ~ 2.5 GB/s means slot and NIC combined need to support at least PCIe 1.1 x16, PCIe 2.0 x8, or PCIe 3.0 x4. (E.g., a PCIe 2.0 x8 card in a PCIe 3.0 x4 slot will only link at PCIe 2.0 x4.)

You can use any suitable tool (like `iperf`) to test with. Make sure the other end is up to the speed as well.

If the slot/mainboard/data sink/source speed isn't up to that throughput you should get a somewhat evenly split performance - there's no guarantee however, sometimes these constructs behave strangely.